# Show image in one half of the sphere

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, panoramas

I would like to show image with resolution 4096x2048 (this is not a spherical image) in one half of the sphere. I use [panoramagl](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/) android library to obtain panoramic view. In my activity which extends com.panoramagl.PLIView I declare:

```
    CustomPLSpherical2Panorama cylindricalPanorama = new CustomPLSpherical2Panorama();
    PLImage imageFace = new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.drawable.spherical_pano), false);
    cylindricalPanorama.setImage(imageFace);
    setPanorama(cylindricalPanorama);
```

In order to don't exceed max texture size which is 1024x1024 I scale this image 2 times down.

```
public class CustomPLSpherical2Panorama extends PLQuadricPanoramaBase {
/**
 * init methods
 */

public CustomPLSpherical2Panorama() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void initializeValues() {
    super.initializeValues();
    this.setPreviewDivs(PLConstants.kDefaultSphere2PreviewDivs);
    this.setDivs(PLConstants.kDefaultSphere2Divs);
}

/**
 * property methods
 */

@Override
public int getTilesNumber() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public void setImage(PLIImage image) {
    if (image != null) {
        int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
        image = image.scale(w / 2, h / 2);
        w = image.getWidth();
        h = image.getHeight();
        if (w >= 128 && w <= 2048 && h >= 64 && h <= 1024 && PLMath.isPowerOfTwo(w) && PLMath.isPowerOfTwo(h) && w % h == 0) {
            int w2 = w >> 1, w32 = w2 >> 4;
            PLIImage frontImage = PLImage.crop(image, w2 - w32, 0, w32 << 1, h);
            PLIImage backImage = PLImage.joinImagesHorizontally(PLImage.crop(image, w - w32, 0, w32, h), PLImage.crop(image, 0, 0, w32, h));
            PLIImage leftImage = PLImage.crop(image, 0, 0, w2, h);
            PLIImage rightImage = PLImage.crop(image, w2, 0, w2, h);
            this.setTexture(new PLTexture(frontImage), PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationFront.ordinal());
            this.setTexture(new PLTexture(backImage), PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationBack.ordinal());
            this.setTexture(new PLTexture(leftImage), PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationLeft.ordinal());
            this.setTexture(new PLTexture(rightImage), PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationRight.ordinal());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * render methods
 */

@Override
protected void internalRender(GL10 gl, PLIRenderer renderer) {
    PLITexture previewTexture = this.getPreviewTextures()[0];
    PLITexture[] textures = this.getTextures();
    PLITexture frontTexture = textures[PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationFront.ordinal()];
    PLITexture backTexture = textures[PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationBack.ordinal()];
    PLITexture leftTexture = textures[PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationLeft.ordinal()];
    PLITexture rightTexture = textures[PLSpherical2FaceOrientation.PLSpherical2FaceOrientationRight.ordinal()];

    boolean frontTextureIsValid = (frontTexture != null && frontTexture.getTextureId(gl) != 0);
    boolean backTextureIsValid = (backTexture != null && backTexture.getTextureId(gl) != 0);
    boolean leftTextureIsValid = (leftTexture != null && leftTexture.getTextureId(gl) != 0);
    boolean rightTextureIsValid = (rightTexture != null && rightTexture.getTextureId(gl) != 0);

    if (frontTextureIsValid || backTextureIsValid || leftTextureIsValid || rightTextureIsValid || (previewTexture != null && previewTexture.getTextureId(gl) != 0)) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        GLUquadric quadratic = this.getQuadric();
        float radius = PLConstants.kPanoramaRadius * 10;
        int divs = this.getDivs();
        int halfDivs = this.getDivs() / 2, quarterDivs = halfDivs / 2;

        if (previewTexture != null) {
            if (frontTextureIsValid && backTextureIsValid && leftTextureIsValid && rightTextureIsValid)
                this.removePreviewTextureAtIndex(0, true);
            else {
                int previewDivs = this.getPreviewDivs();
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, previewTexture.getTextureId(gl));
                GLUES.gluSphere(gl, quadratic, radius, previewDivs, previewDivs);
            }
        }

        // Front Face
        if (frontTextureIsValid) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTexture.getTextureId(gl));
            GLUES.glu3DArc(gl, quadratic, PLConstants.kPI8, -PLConstants.kPI16, false, radius, quarterDivs, quarterDivs);
        }

        // Back Face
        if (backTextureIsValid) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, backTexture.getTextureId(gl));
            GLUES.glu3DArc(gl, quadratic, PLConstants.kPI8, -PLConstants.kPI16, true, radius, quarterDivs, quarterDivs);
        }

        // Left Face
        if (leftTextureIsValid) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, leftTexture.getTextureId(gl));
            GLUES.gluHemisphere(gl, quadratic, false, radius, halfDivs, halfDivs);
            //GLUES.gluPartialDisk(gl, quadratic, 0, PLConstants.kPI16, quarterDivs, quarterDivs, PLConstants.kPI16, PLConstants.kPI8);
        }

        //Right Face
        if (rightTextureIsValid) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, rightTexture.getTextureId(gl));
            GLUES.gluHemisphere(gl, quadratic, true, radius, halfDivs, halfDivs);
        }

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

}

Above code help me show my image in sphere but the problem is that the image isn't spherical so it stretches too much at the bottom and top of the sphere.

The best solution for that problem could be as black area shows at below image:
[image]

It should show from -90 to +90 degrees horizontally and from -90 to +90 degrees vertically (ideally should be -80 to +80 degrees vertically).
I tried to use:

```
public static void gluPartialDisk(GL10 gl, GLUquadric qobj, float innerRadius, float outerRadius, int slices, int loops, float startAngle, float sweepAngle)
```

but it doesn't work. It shows black screen.

To sum up the questions are:

1. **How to show image on the sphere as black area shows on the image?**
2. **How to set min, max horizontal and vertical rotation in degrees (in [user guide](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/wiki/UserGuide) is atvMin, atvMax, athMin, athMax option but I couldn't find it in panoramagl source code)?**

Comment: You need to find an appropriate mapping of the texture onto the sphere, that's all.

Comment: Could you give me more info?

Answer (score 0):

1) What about using PLCylindricalPanorama setting correct height?

2) atvMin, atvMax, athMin, athMax are in PLConstants as:

for **atv**:

```
public static final float kDefaultPitchMinRange = -90.0f;
public static final float kDefaultPitchMaxRange =  90.0f;
```

for **ath**:

```
public static final float kRotationMinValue =   -180.0f;
public static final float kRotationMaxValue =    180.0f;
```